# Continuous Kähler differentials over the ring of power series

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R=k[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$ be the ring of power series over a field $k$. Assume that $\widehat{\texttt{Der}_k(R)}$ stands for the module of continuous $k-$linear derivations of $R$ and $\widehat{\Omega_{R/k}}$ is the module continuous Kahler differentials. Is the following true $$\widehat{\texttt{Der}_k(R)}\cong_R \texttt{Hom}_R(\widehat{\Omega_{R/k}},R)$$.

Comment: I haven't heard the term "continous Kähler differentials" before. Can you define it?